# Can Scoold be used with Azure Active Directory accounts?

Tags: scoold

Scoold offers many integrations with various Identity Providers. One of them is Microsoft. Does it mean that Azure Active Directory tenant accounts will also work?

Comment: Oh, I noticed that there is also generic OAuth2 support. I'll try using that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Scoold supports Microsoft as an identity provider which means that Azure AD should also work out of the box.

Here's an example configuration for authenticating with Azure:

```js
para.ms_app_id = "11c8ad77-867b-440-123-456"
para.ms_secret = "secret"
para.ms_tenant_id = "91373c07-6bab-4ab1-86b6-03d7d7e685d9"
```